# What is the reason that the Android Emulator loads slowly?

Tags: android, android-emulator, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the Android phone simulator so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500616/why-is-the-android-phone-simulator-so-slow)

Hi, I am new to Android development, and I wonder why the Emulator loads so slowly, especially when I create an emulator for Android 4.0 apps.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=19&gs_id=2x&xhr=t&q=why+is+the+android+emulator+so+slow&tok=hSFdrm0w8oC6bcTiKyzJsA&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&pbx=1&oq=why+is+the+android+&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=ee50a85590b9a705&biw=1680&bih=869

Comment: A handy tip for the simulator is to put it on a core of its own, so that it can execute on a single core without being interrupted. You can do this on the Windows Task Manager by right clicking it and clicking set affinity, then put it on one of your cores and restrict any heavy programs, eg Eclipse, from that core to prevent them from interfering with it.

Comment: Also enable snapshots, this bypasses boot and loads the last snapshot saved of the system. It must boot once, but after that its much quicker.

Comment: definitely enable screenshots. It starts almost instantly when loading from a screenshot.

Answer (score 6):

Usually this is tied directly to the speed of your development system. Increase the amount of RAM, disk speed, processor cores etc. and you'll see a noticeable improvement.

Also, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975469/speed-up-android-emulator) for some more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's slow because it runs Android on emulated hardware (an ARM CPU, IIRC).  So you're running a complete virtual machine, not just a sandboxed OS.  And since it emulates a single-core machine, having multiple cores on your development box doesn't help much.  You're better off with a dual-core 3.5GHz machine than a 4-core box running at 2.5GHz.

Answer (score 0):

Android Emulator is the virtual Device of android OS. It takes ram and Memory from the host OS that why the ram and the memory is shared by the Emulator.
As because it is slow in process.